# How to connect mongoose databse in nest spec file?

Tags: typescript, testing, mongoose

I try to connect mongoose to my nest controller spec file. After a lot of researches and tests, I still can't access my data.
Has anyone ever had this type of issue and found a solution ?

PS: I didn't post some code since nothing work so far but you can see the project [here](https://github.com/vivitek/backend/tree/feature/nest/server2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it's useless to inject your Model in you spec file, just found this solution, it's not perfect but it works ¯_(ツ)_/¯

```js
import { INestApplication } from "@nestjs/common"
import { Test } from "@nestjs/testing"
import * as request from "supertest"
import { AppModule } from "../app.module"


describe('Foo Controller', () => {
  const url: string = "/foo"
  let server: any;
  let app: INestApplication

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule]
    }).compile()

    app = module.createNestApplication()
    server = app.getHttpServer()
    await app.init()
  })

  it('Should be defined', () => {
    expect(module).toBeDefined()
    expect(app).toBeDefined()
    expect(server).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('/ [GET]', async () => {
    const res = await request(server).get(url)
    expect(res).to[...]
  })

  afterEach(async () => {
    await app.close()
  })
})
```